# Multiple lines of text are being highlighted every time I click

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I've had this weird/annoying problem appear a few times now in Mathematica 10.4 where whenever I click, it highlights everything from the bottom of the cell to my cursor.  If I click outside a cell, it highlights all cells from the bottom of the notebook.  The problem goes away temporarily when I quit and restart, but I can't figure out how to fix it otherwise.

Edit: If it helps, I've figured out that it seems to happen when I bring another application to the foreground and then switch back to the Mathematica window.